# Scala - Java class Vector is not a value

Tags: java, scala, vector

I am fairly new to Scala and looking into Vectors, however I am having some issues with a Vector assignment.
I get the error `error: Java class Vector is not a value` relating to `val v1 = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` this occurs in a file and in the REPL
When looking online that appears to be the correct implementation.
Scala is version `2.12.5`

Comment: I guess you must have java imports somewhere . so an explicit import should do the trick I guess. `import scala.Vector`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That seems to do the trick, I have `import java.io.FileWriter`. So guessing that is causing it to pull in some Java Vectors instead?

Comment: yeah :) glad that you sorted out

Comment: No, if you `import java.io.FileWriter`, it will add *exactly one symbol* into the scope, namely the class `java.io.FileWriter`, and nothing else. Check whether you've something like `import java.util._` somewhere.